# Handling multiple balances with expiry dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm

***The Problem :*** 
Consider a bank which issues accounts to its users with multiple balances with expiry i.e the amount credited in your account today will expire exactly after six months. lets say you got 500$ today(2nd june,2018) , this balance will expire on (2nd December,2018 ).
Now consider the following balances table of a customer tim.

```
id  balance createdAt     expiry
001     100     4th November 2017 4th May 2018
002     200     2nd January 2018  2nd July 2018
003     100     10th Feb 2018     10th August 2018
```

If the user wishes to spend 250 on some product today(2nd june ,2018) , these 250 units should be subtracted step wise from all available unexpired balances and expired rows has to be cleared.

Therefore the balances table after the purchase should be

```
id  balance createdAt     expiry
003     50  10th Feb 2018 10th August 2018
```

***the solution i have***

1. get all rows of user balances in ascending of expiry
2. remove all rows which are expired
3. iterate over other rows
4. if spending - balance in row > 0 then delete the row and do spending 
   =spending-balance in row.
5. if spending - balance in row <=0 then update row set balance = balance - 
   spending

***what am i expecting***
*Can the above solution be implemented in a more clever way.*

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: Simply select all rows that haven't expired in or order. IOW expiry date > today. Iterate through those, updating the balance until you have used up the amount spent. Ignore those rows where the expiry date has past.

Comment: You could try this: Iterate over each row without sorting or anything. If expiry < today, delete, else, deduct spending from balance. This way, you could minimize the operations it takes to sort. You don't necessarily have to remove all the expired entries.

Comment: @VidorVistrom that would not be fair to users, who should presumably be able to spend the points nearest to expiration, first.  You also almost certainly wouldn't just "delete" expired rows... there needs to be some accounting of disappearing points.

Comment: @SrinivasSunil if you are keeping track of points by simply decrementing balances, you will have a more serious problem, eventually.  There should be a table of transactions that sum to the balances or you will eventually find yourself at a loss to explain how some of the balances arrived at their current state.  The transactions should be the truth, and the balances non-authoritative.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I also maintain a transactions table. All I was looking is for a better way to organise and work with these expiring balances. Thank you